# Angular dev build fail, prod build works

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've a problem with my CI and angular dev build. I didn't change anything in my code and now I can't do a dev build on an server (it works on my vm). The log says I've got an error into my code but I didn't change something in this part. Morever, the build prod works perfectly.

The problem appears on a server where I build my application through git lab ci. It worked perfectly until now.

**The error I've got :**

```
ERROR in src/Site/coreModule/sidenav/sidenav.extended.service.ts(73,21): error TS2339: Property 'customClass' does not exist on type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...'.
  Property 'customClass' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/Site/coreModule/sidenav/sidenav.extended.service.ts(74,22): error TS2339: Property 'customClass' does not exist on type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...'.
  Property 'customClass' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/Site/coreModule/sidenav/sidenav.extended.service.ts(76,22): error TS2339: Property 'customClass' does not exist on type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...'.
  Property 'customClass' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/Site/coreModule/sidenav/sidenav.extended.service.ts(80,27): error TS2339: Property 'hasParent' does not exist on type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...'.
  Property 'hasParent' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/Site/coreModule/sidenav/sidenav.extended.service.ts(81,49): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/sidenav/sidenav.service.ts(110,22): error TS2339: Property 'hasParent' does not exist on type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...'.
  Property 'hasParent' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/Site/themeModule/sidenav/sidenav.service.ts(111,42): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(32,54): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(37,40): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(50,47): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(53,42): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(56,50): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(59,43): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
src/Site/themeModule/toolbar/search-bar/search-bar.component.ts(62,47): error TS2345: Argument of type 'number | ((callbackfn: (value: SidenavItem, index: number, array: SidenavItem[]) => void, thisArg...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SidenavItem'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SidenavItem'.
```

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Backoffice-master",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "config": "ts-node git.version.ts",
    "start": "npm run config && ng serve --env=vm --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --port 4200 --live-reload false",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --env=prod -vc=true --build-optimizer --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks --output-path=dist/prod",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --disable-host-check --port 4200 --env=e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "5.2.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "1.0.5",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "1.1.0",
    "angular-sortablejs": "2.1.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "css-element-queries": "0.4.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "9.12.0",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.5",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "1.0.9",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.2.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "5.0.0-9",
    "ngx-permissions": "4.1.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "2.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.7.2",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "screenfull": "3.3.2",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "8.2.6",
    "sortablejs": "1.6.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.10.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "6.0.90",
    "codelyzer": "4.1.0",
    "jasmine": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "tslint": "5.9.1"
  }
}
```

**My gitlab ci :**

```
cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - node_modules/
      - dist/

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - rm ./package-lock.json
        - npm install
        - npm run config
        - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --env=dev --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks --output-path=dist/dev/
        - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --env=int -vc=true --build-optimizer --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks --output-path=dist/int/
        - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --env=prod -vc=true --build-optimizer --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks --output-path=dist/prod/
    when: manual
    only:
        - tags
```

**Version :**

npm -> 5.6.0
Ubuntu -> 16.04

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't know why your build is failing, but I sure know you can correct your issues and it will work again. Why don't you just do that ? Do you really need to find the error in your build ? If so, you should give your project repository, along with your environments, to the Angular team and open an issue on their repo.

Comment: Something new about this problem. If I git clone my project in a fresh directory on my virtual machine, I've got the problem.

Comment: I believe you've run `npm i` beforehand ? the problem could come from the fact that you fixed your dependency versions, and you did not run on a fresh `npm i`. This means that on your local device, you don't actually have those packages, but other versions of them. Try deleting your `node_modules`, and run `npm i` locally.

Comment: I fixed the problem on my virtual machine by updating my package.json file. Now, when I git clone my repo I can build but still the same problem on a server  (I tried to build the project on another vm and it works...)